# Is it possible to check if a LinkedIn company or group exists without OAuth?

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

As part of my internship, I'm making a 'brandchecker' where you enter your new company name and it checks for you if domains (.com, .net, .org, .nl) have been taken, and if Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn pages have been taken. I'm at the LinkedIn part now, and I just need to know if the page exists. I don't have to see posts, members, membercounts or anything of the likes, I just need to know if it exists.

The [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search) says I can do that, I just have to authorise the session (?) with OAuth. I honestly don't know anything about OAuth, but something tells me there HAS to be another way to check if the companypage or group does or does not exist.

Is there another way to check if the company or group exists without using OAuth?

Thanks!

Comment: You've answered yourself: The LinkedIn API says I can do that, I just have to authorise the session with OAuth. You dont know anything of OAuth, so it should be natural that you should want to know something of OAuth, thats how you learn things.

Comment: You can probably do this by scraping the page, but doing so will probably be more hassle than it is worth. Can you point us to the part of the docs you are reading, by hyperlinking in your question? APIs don't usually need OAuth, so maybe you are misreading something.

Comment: I linked to the API. I figured scraping the page would be too much of a hassle. I have no idea howmuch of an effort OAuth is, but I honestly don't know if it's worth setting up OAuth for one lousy brandchecker for an internship..

Comment: Linkedin want to know who is using their API, so unfortunately you need to jump through their hoops.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that hard and since the access token is valid for 60 days, you can manually get one like this:

1. register an application on https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer with a bogus `redirect_uri` like `https://bogus.com/linkedin` and copy the generated `consumer key` and `consumer secret`
2. type in your browser bar `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<consumer_key>&state=bogus&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbogus.com%2Flinkedin`
3. login and your accept the client's permissions, then you'll get redirected to a non-functional URL like `https://bogus.com/linkedin?code=<code>`
4. copy the `code` value from that URL in to the following CURL command:

   `curl "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbogus.com%2Flinkedin&client_id=<consumer_key>&client_secret=<consumer_secret>"`

and your access token will be in the response like:

```
{"access_token":"<token>","expires_in":5174190}
```

you can then make a call like:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/company-search?keywords=<name>&format=json"
```

well the PHP equivalent of that:

```
$headers = array(
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
  'x-li-format: json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$r = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Can you be little more specific about these url you provide, 
Firstly `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<consumer_key>&state=bogus&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fbogus.com%2Flinkedin` what is state parameter do and what is the value of it, also how can i get the redirect_uri for a specific page ?
Secondly: what is bogus.com here?
Thirdly : If there any way to create access token automatically using PHP script ?